# Magento 2 best practice for class locations and names

Tags: magento2, extensions, best-practice, architecture, naming-convention

In `Magento 1` we were used to place our classes in these directories

- Block
- Helper
- Model
- Resource

and use a simple class name without any capital letters in the middle of the name.

If we take a look at some cases in `Magento 2 Core`

### **Helpers**

**Location**:
- `\Foo\Bar\Helper`
**Name**:
- `*.php`
**Examples**:
- `\Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Report`
- `\Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images`

---

### **Observers**

**Location**:
- `\Foo\Bar\Observer`
**Name**:
- `*.php`
- `*Observer.php`
**Examples**:
- `\Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Observer\SalesOrderAddressAfterLoad`
- `\Magento\CustomerBalance\Observer\ProcessBeforeOrderPlaceObserver`

---

### **Plugins**

**Location**:
- `\Foo\Bar\Plugin`
**Name**:
- `*.php`
- `*Plugin.php`
**Examples**:
- `\Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu`
- `\Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin`
**Source**: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#declaring-a-plugin

---

### **ConfigProvider**

**Location**:
- `\Foo\Bar\Model`
**Name**:
- `*ConfigProvider.php`
**Examples**:
- `\Magento\Tax\Model\TaxConfigProvider`
- `\Magento\Payment\Model\IframeConfigProvider`

---

My questions are :

- If there is any `good` / `bad` / `best` practices for that in `Magento 2` ?
- If I want to create a custom `DataProvider` for example what it will be ?

  - `\Foo\Bar\Provider\CustomDataProvider`
  - `\Foo\Bar\DataProvider\Custom`
  - `\Foo\Bar\Model\Provider\CustomDataProvider`
  - `\Foo\Bar\Helper\Provider\CustomDataProvider`
- How to determine the construction of the class name and location, a folder at the root of the module, in Model, in Helper, etc?
- Does it depends on retrieved data source / data type ?
- When do we have to add the suffix to the class name ?

---

A part of a response for the `Virtual Types` : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Virtual-Types-Naming-Convention/ba-p/61510

Answer (score 10):

Magento 2 is not restricted as Magento 1 to only a few folders like block, helper, model and so on.
You can basically place a class in any folder you want. It's up to you since the class are instantiated using the full class name not with aliases as in Magento 1.

My recommendation is to group them by the functionality.

- observers in `Vendor/Module/Observer`.
- plugins in `Vendor/Module/Plugin`
- data providers in `Vendor/Module/DataProvider`.
- ui component related classes in `Vendor/Module/Ui`

but try to avoid name duplication.  I mean `Vendor/Module/DataProvider/CustomDataProvider` would be redundant.

Maybe the suffix can be added for interfaces only, although people would argue against it.

To summarize, it's up to you how you do it, just be consistent in it.

From the functionality point of view it's not important where you place the classes. You can even go crazy with them and place all of them directly in `Vendor/Module` folder, but you probably don't want that.

I think (but not completely sure) that the only restriction is that controllers must be in the folder `Controller`.

Comment: I agree we can go crazy, it is a good point as much as a bad one but as you said it is according to our way of seeing things. Maybe when Magento shares their internal technical visions as announced at the MagentoLive France we will have more information on these points Thank you for sharing your opinion

Answer (score 9):

I think the top priority should be to make the code as *self documenting* as possible.
So rather than putting everything into Model or Helper directories, finding a good name that describes what the code underneath does is a better approach.
Of course, it's also harder because it requires a lot more thinking.

For example, rather than using `Model/Config/Converter.php`,  the name `OrderStateMachine/TransitionsConfiguration/XmlToArrayConverter.php` says a lot more what a Module and a class does.

Comment: As you said it require more thinking to make it clear for us but also for anyone seeing the extension. That make things harder at the moment but more effective over time. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 7):

I reckon it's opinion based but I agree that there are some inconsistencies regarding class naming and locations in M2.

**Here's the list I came up with regarding folder naming.** To me you should always use those folders when you can in order to make your module easier to browse and understand for anyone else:

- Block
- Controller
- Model
- Observer
- Setup
- Test
- Ui
- etc
- i18n
- view
- Cron
- Helper
- Console
- Api
- Plugin
- DataProvider

On top of that, M2 uses some very specific folders but I haven't included them in this list:

- Pricing
- App
- CustomerData
- Service
- Gateway
- Files
- Adapter
- Component
- TemplateEngine

**The good thing with M2 is that you can use and create whatever folder you need. If something does not belong in the list above, create your own folder and put your classes in them just try to be consistent.**

Comment: In all your answers we find the same idea, the possibility to do as we want, the most important being to remain consistent and regular in its construction. However it would be great for Magento to share some internal visions on this as they announced to the ML. As you said it will be easier for everyone to understand Core and Community extensions. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are already some really good answers above. What I would like to add is that you should avoid placing code under `app/code` and instead use a composer based installation method which will end up placing your code under `vendor/`.

Comment: Yes don't worry I am aware of that, the format is just for the example in my question :) But you are right for the people who don't know that I will edit to make it clear. Thank you

Comment: that is good point fooman